# PHP: PDO Query data from different tables

Tags: php, sql, select, pdo

I would like to ask assistance to help me solve my coding problem, I would like to obtain information from two tables in the same database.

DB structure:

Table Name: _net

```
id
name
ip
comment
```

I can get all relevant details from this table with the following code:

```
$netsql = 'SELECT * FROM _net ORDER BY id';
$qnet = $conn->query($netsql);
$qnet->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Table: _net_port (other information I require to do a query)

```
id
netid
port
comment
```

I would like to obtain the information from table _net_port where the relevant id = to netid (id in Table _net will be the same as netid in Table _net_port. Especially to obtain the list of ports.

Comment: you need to learn about INNER JOINs in SQL. This is nothing to do with PHP or PDO specifically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join the `_net` table on an aggregate query of `_net_port` with `group_concat`:

```sql
SELECT n.*, p.ports
FROM   _net n
JOIN   (SELECT   netid, GROUP_CONCAT(port)
        FROM     _net_ports
        GROUP BY netid) p ON n.id = p.netid
```

Answer (score 1):

You need [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

```
SELECT * FROM _net ORDER BY id
INNER JOIN _net_port ON _net_port.id = _net.id
```

Your question is about MySQL, not about PHP script.